# How to get the array values which the array created in function?

Tags: php, arrays, function

When I think about the functional of array and I tried to create an array and store in the function acts as the clock but how can I get the array values outside the function?

```
 function theClock($a,$b,$c){
    $time['Hour'] = $a;
    $time['Minute'] = $b;
    $time['Seconds'] = $c;
    return $time;
 }

  //How can I call the array values in there that $time is stored?
```

I am a beginner of PHP and I want to improve my concept, I am very grateful if anyone can helps, Cheers!

Sorry, I forgot to mention that I would like to use foreach() to shows the array values as the table form.

```
  $show1 = '<table border ="1" >';
    foreach($time as $ck => $tk){
        $show1 .= '<tr><td>' . $ck . '</td><td>' . $tk . '</td></tr>';                       
    }
    $show1 .= '</table>';

    $show2 = '<table border ="1">';     
        foreach($time as $tk){
            $show2 .= '<td>' . $tk . '</td>';
            $show2 .= '<td>:</td>';
        }
    $show2 .= '</table>';

        echo $show1;    
        echo $show2;
theClock(11,12,13);
```

Comment: Simply by `$your_array = clock(1,20,20);`.

Comment: It shows NULL from var_dump. Also I have tried this method.

Comment: @chchk127 No, really, it is working fine. Where is your function defined in your code ?

Comment: @chchk127 no, it doesn't - http://codepad.viper-7.com/BMrWAO

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function clock($a,$b,$c){
   $time['Hour'] = $a;
   $time['Minute'] = $b;
   $time['Seconds'] = $c;
   return $time;
}

$time = clock(12, 30, 00);
$hour = $time['Hour'];
$minute = $time['Minute'];
$seconds = $time['Seconds'];
print $hour; // 12
print $minute; // 30
print $seconds; // 00
```

As per your edit, to use in a foreach loop:

```
$html = '<table border ="1" >';
foreach($time as $unit => $value){
    $html .= "<tr><td>$unit:</td><td>$value</td></tr>";
}
$html .= '</table>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by just calling your function with your parameters like

```
$time = clock(10,20,30);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$time = clock(12, 40, 15);
echo "<pre>";print_r($time);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$vararr=clock($a,$b,$c);
```